# Use Outlook to use a different sender address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I've migrated from Thunderbird to Outlook 2016, and I'm looking for a specific feature I did have before but which I cannot find in Outlook. I want to send e-mail with a specific sender.

Basically I have two IMAP mail accounts now in Outlook:

1. `firstname@xyz.com`
2. `catch-all@xyz.com`

On my web host I've configured a few more e-mail aliases like `info@xyz.com` and `git@xyz.com` which all just fall through to the `catch-all` mail address for *incoming* mail (they *are* allowed as a sender). In Outlook I see them in the Inbox for that account, which is great. When replying, I want the "*From*" field to be the other accounts.

You can show the "*From*" address in the Compose window, then click "*Send From Other Email Address*", and fill it out like this:

[image: Send from Other Email with info@xyz.nl]

But then I receive e-mail with a sender like this:

> John Doe <catch-all@xyz.nl> on behalf of info@xyz.nl

Which is *not* what I want. If I check the full headers I can see that only the `Reply-to` and `From` fields are set to `info@xyz.nl`. I want it to be just `John Doe <info@xyz.nl>`.

Since I have about 10 of these mail aliases, I'd hate to go through setting up separate e-mail accounts in Outlook for all of them (not in the least because I don't *want* them to appear as inboxes in the left-hand pane of Outlook).

In Thunderbird I could just create new Identities and use an existing outgoing SMTP configuration from my catch-all account. Is there something similar in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do what you want but in regards to the multiple inboxes you can avoid that by creating all the other accounts as POP3 accounts instead of IMAP and disable send/receive for them. It does not matter if the POP3 server info is invalid as you will not really be pulling email from them, only the SMTP settings needs to be valid so you can send.

An added benefit of this approach is that you don't need to use the from field and manually type the address you want to send with, instead the Send button will have an arrow on it with a drop down that will allow you to quickly choose the account you want to use to send the email vs the default one...

Comment: Can you go into more detail on how the OP would go about setting this up?